# hacer fetch a una API sin SSL

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, ssl, https

monte un servidor local y ya regresa un arreglo con un objeto, puedo acceder a el desde postman pero cuando intento hacer un fetch me dice que no es una dirección HTTPS no tengo ip publica fija así que no puedo agregar un certificado SSL. ¿alguien conoce alguna alternativa?

```
function getDatos(){
  fetch("http://iserbeer.ddns.net/")
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data =>{
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
}

getDatos()
```

Comment: Estás desde Vanilla JS o en algún framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por motivos de seguridad, no puedes enviar una petición desde HTTP hasta HTTPS y viceversa, pero lo que si puedes hacer es usar APIs como CORS-Anywhere

Además esta API tiene ventajas como que puedes saltarte el CORS

Dicho esto, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```javascript
fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/url",{method:"GET", headers: { origin:"dominio.com" })
.then(resp => {resp.text()}).then(resp => {console.log(resp)})
.catch(err => {console.log("error", err)});
```

La forma de uso:

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/URL-De-Petición`

Tienes que especificar `origin` antes de la petición